# Is there a difference between setting "onclick" directly in HTML vs. via the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Why is `logfunc` "not defined"?

```
  var logfunc = function(obj) {
     return function() {
       console.log(obj)
     }
   }

  t += '<a onclick="logfunc(this)">&lt;</a>'
```

Comment: I think we'll need a little more context than that.  Can you expand your example to be *complete* (i.e., more or less a full HTML document)?  And are you getting an error?  Please provide the full error text if possible.

Comment: Is `logfunc` defined inside another function?  What happens if you remove the `var` keyword in front of it to anchor it to `window`?

Comment: @Phoenix: good question, the code sample doesn't really offer much. I've speculated in my answer that the assignment may have been made within another function's scope thus invalidating the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference to `longfunc` would not be accessible if it is declared outside of global scope, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/A5H2H/)

I'm not advocating declaring variables directly in the global scope by omitting `var` but it makes a good example:

```
function setupStuff() {
    var logfunc = function(obj) { //defined within setupStuff scope
        /*...*/
    }
    t += '<a onclick="logfunc(this)">&lt;</a>';
}

function setupStuffDifferently() {
    logfuncB = function(obj) { //defined in the global scope
       /*...*/
    }
    t += '<a onclick="logfuncB(this)">&lt;</a>';
}
```

I would much rather see the function declared separately like

```
t += '<a onclick="logfunc(this)">&lt;</a>';

function logfunc(obj) { //this would work when assigned through `onclick`
       /*...*/
}
```

If the option is available to you, I'd suggest using a library like jQuery which offers more flexibility in [assigning and handling click events](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a "logfunc is not defined" error because your `logfunc` is not in the global (i.e. `window`) scope and functions that are bound using HTML element attributes must be global.

You can get around that by saying:

```
window.logfunc = function(obj) {
  return function() {
    console.log(obj)
  }
};
```

But that still won't do what you think it does since `logfunc` just returns a function that calls `console.log` and the `<a>` won't know that it is supposed to call the `function() { console.log(obj) }` function, it will just see it as a true value. I think you want:

```
window.logfunc = function(obj) {
  console.log(obj)
};
```

if you want clicking the link to produce a console message.

As far as the "what are differences between `onclick` and via the DOM" goes:

1. Functions attached through attributes must be global and that quickly leads to a big tangled mess.
2. You can only attach one function per element using `onclick` but you can call [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) as often as you want. You can get around this limitation if you want to paste JavaScript snippets together as strings but that's nasty.
3. Similarly, you can easily undo an `addEventListener` call using [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeEventListener); removing an event handler from an `onclick` attribute involves even nastier string wrangling than adding one does.
4. Using `onclick` unnecessarily entangles your HTML and JavaScript and that leads to a maintenance nightmare.